# Solving algebraic equations with modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I solve for 'b' given:

$1 \equiv a\pmod{2} \\ a=\frac{b-1}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward.

The first line states that a is odd.

The second line states that $ \frac{b-1}{3}$ must equal a and that way must also be odd.

$ \frac{b-1}{3}$ is odd if b-1 is a multiple of 3 with an odd number.

Set  $ b-1 = 3 \cdot (2n+1) = 6n+3, n>=0 $

So $ b = 6n+4 $ and of course $ a = \frac{b-1}{3} = 2n+1 $ for $ n>= 0 $

Comment: Is there a way to derive $2(n+1)$ from $1 \equiv a (\mod n)$ ? Can I just treat the modulus as division?